# No HTML viewer plugins available for Claws Mail any more?

Tags: debian, claws-mail

I have been using [Claws Mail](http://www.claws-mail.org) as my email client for almost a decade.  It's fast, configurable and friendly.

However, it does not natively display HTML mail.  For that you need a plugin, and three were earlier available - the [Gtkhtml2](http://www.claws-mail.org/plugin-gtkhtml2.php) plugin, the Fancy plugin and the Dillo plugin.

I use Claws on Debian, and recently the Fancy plugin stopped working because of what looked like a filesystem issue.  I uninstalled it and tried to reinstall it, only to discover that the Debian repositories no longer contain any installable candidate for 32-bit x86 systems.  I gather [there have been security concerns](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=222160&p=2) with this plugin.

But the Debian repositories do not contain either the Dillo plugin or the  Gtkhtml2 plugin.  The stable [code tarball](http://www.claws-mail.org/download.php?file=releases/claws-mail-3.15.1.tar.gz) for version 3.15.1 does not contain them either, so I can't compile them.  The git tree includes the dillo plugin, but I'm reluctant to use that as I'll have to compile the entire client from what appears to be a development snapshot.

Is there now no stable HTML viewer for Claws Mail?  I am really hoping that this isn't true, because then I'll have to switch clients (the non-HTML display method just doesn't cut it when most emails are now in HTML), and I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ apt-cache policy claws-mail-fancy-plugin
claws-mail-fancy-plugin:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.14.1-3+b1
  Version table:
     3.14.1-3+b1 500
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
```

And it's also [available in Sid](https://packages.debian.org/sid/claws-mail-fancy-plugin), so it looks like you might have some APT misconfiguration problem or the package for that plugin Fancy was renamed etc.

Let's work from there.

Comment: The sid package is available only for amd64 (and that's an out of date port) and hurd-i386. But you're right about stretch. Will try again

Comment: @ShankarG I'd mail the package's maintainers then. Another possibility is to mail `debian-devel at lists.debian.org`
SO is really not fit for such questions: to my knowledge, Debian developers do not frequent it.

Comment: You were correct, my apt was tracking testing and I hadn't included stretch / jessie in my sources.list.  I downgraded claws and it now seems to be installing properly.  I'll write to the list later to ask why these plugins have been removed from testing / sid (for i386 at least)

Answer (score 1):

The fancy plugin has been removed because it depends on `libwebkitgtk-1.0-0`, which has been removed from Debian 9: https://bugs.debian.org/790199